# Excel freezes when hiding sheets, runs after VBA

Tags: vba, freeze

I have made an excel with multiple sheets. Some of the sheets have VBA code. When I try to hide / unhide sheets, it sometimes freezes excel. When I run any routine in VBA (opened in a separate window), it becomes normal. I can't understand why excel freezes.

**Update**

I had not posted any code earlier as I thought it is something generic, since I believed no code was executed in hiding / unhiding sheets. I have figured out the problem. I had the following code in the worksheet_activate event in a worksheet. I believe it is the
    "Application.screenUpdating = False" 
which was causing the issue.

The problem happened when I was trying to hide some other sheet such that this sheet would become active, or when I was trying to unhide this sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim c As Range

'show relevant fields
For Each c In Range("hide")
If c.Value = "hide" Then
c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Neither do we, because we can't see the code you're running, and you've provided no information that would allow us to help you. If you want help, you need to provide enough details and include code; we can't see your screen, examine the spreadsheet, or read your mind, so we only have what you tell us to go on. If you don't share the information, we can't help solve the problem. In order for us to help, you need to [edit] your question and provide a lot more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is OK and even recommended in a lot of situations, but you need to be sure that you set it back to `True`:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'...
'do some operations that will cause 
'the screen to flash, like opening 
'lots of files or manipulating ranges
'on active sheet
'...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'...
'not worried about screen updates anymore
'...
```